# Mathematica: Exportation of Plot3D changes position of graphic

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hello dear **stack overflow** community,

I am exporting a 3D plot from `Mathematica`, but it messes up the position I want to save it.
The position I intend to save the graphic is the one I aligned manually when visualizing it, however when exported, the plot is in its default position.
Objective: Using *Export* command, export the *Plot3D* without changing the position I want.

My sincere acknowledgements

Comment: After manual adjustment right click on the plot and select "Save Graphic As", select the format and provide a filename.

Comment: So there is no way to do it via ```Export``` command?

Comment: You can [extract the view](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/extract-current-viewing-parameters-from-a-3d-view) from the graphic.